# Format main page post excerpt previews

Tags: excerpt

For my posts, I use a block quote/pull quote at the top of them all to highlight a key sentence that is contained in the body of the post.

The only problem is the post excerpts also pull this line in at the beginning of the excerpt previews on other pages.

So now I end up with a post preview that doesn't read correctly.

What is a good way to eliminate the excerpt from pulling in what I put in the block/pull quote from the main post?

**Example:**

The post starts:

> "Supa Gaming is an Indonesian YouTube channel specializing in
> instructional videos which guide viewers through the process of
> beating difficult boss-levels in various games which are popular among
> younger children."

Down in the post is a line I am using in my opening block quote that says

> "Seeing as a given piece of content on this channel does not include
> any commentary, explicit language is never an issue..."

So now my post excerpt preview on my main page reads:

> "Seeing as a given piece of content on this channel does not include
> any commentary, explicit language is never an issue... Supa Gaming is
> an Indonesian YouTube channel specializing in instructional videos
> which guide viewers through the process of beating difficult
> boss-levels in various games which are popular among younger
> children."

As you can see...that doesn't work, so I am trying to find a fix. Tried about 15 links in google and didn't find any sort of solution.

Comment: Have you looked at custom meta fields?  You could have the quote be in a separate field that you could only display on the post singles (either by hook or by editing the single.php template.) and then it wouldn't be pulled in the roll on the homepage.

Comment: I hadnt but I'll go look at those now.